# Issue with insertion image in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I am inserting the image in the content of ckeditor 4.4.0.
when i put url of image like http://www.asge.org/uploadedImages/Patients/National_Colorectal_Cancer_Awareness_Month/NCCAM_Banner_36x12.jpg
 and set the image size and position. 
the image comes correct on current preview. after this i  save the data into database it **filter the img style tag from html due to which i am not getting correct img**.
my current ckeditor config is

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
// config.toolbar = 'Full';

config.toolbarGroups =
[
    { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton', 
        'HiddenField' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv',
    '-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
];
config.allowedContent= 'true';

 };
```

My input data:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.asge.org/uploadedImages/Patients/National_Colorectal_Cancer_Awareness_Month/NCCAM_Banner_36x12.jpg" style="float:right; height:100px; width:300px" />
```

Output data:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.asge.org/uploadedImages/Patients/National_Colorectal_Cancer_Awareness_Month/NCCAM_Banner_36x12.jpg"  />
```

Comment: Could you show the data as you expect it, and the data as it is turning out? It's not entirely clear...

Comment: @JamieBarker please check out edit part..

Comment: If you right click on the image and click "Image Properties", do you have an "Advanced" tab? If you don't, try [adding it](http://ckeditor.com/addon/dialogadvtab)

Answer (score 0):

**WRONG**:

```
config.allowedContent= 'true';
```

OK:

```
config.allowedContent= true;
```

BTW. You also configure toolbar incorrectly. Note that there are two settings - [`config.toolbar`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) and [`config.toolbarGroups`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarGroups). Read more in the [Toolbar customization](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_toolbar) guide.

Comment: Cache? PS. Updated my answer, because the toolbar configuration is also incorrect.